# Connecting Two iOS Devices via Node.js Server Backend

Tags: ios, node.js, swift, server

I'm fairly new to swift and backend development, so please take it easy on me if my logic is flawed.

I'm trying to build an uber style app for ios and have a user side interface, a driver side interface, and a backend built in node.js.  My question is how do I communicate when someone has chosen a "driver" from the user side to the driver side.  I'm assuming it's a combination of a put request from the user side with get requests from the driver side, but I'm confused as to how to notify the driver side app when changes have occurred.  Do I have to constantly be making get requests to the database or is there a better way to hold a connection between node and the app?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You should research [Apple's notifications](https://developer.apple.com/notifications/) to see if it meets your needs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me start out by saying that I don't have any personal experience with the technologies/frameworks I mention here (apart from Realm, but not for the purpose you're after), so, consider this a list of things you could look into.

### Websockets

One way of doing this could be using *websockets* to hold the connection. If that is what you're after, then you could look at [this tutorial](https://www.raywenderlich.com/143874/websockets-ios-starscream) about using websockets in an iOS app.

However...I can see some problems using straight websockets. For instance: what happens if your app is backgrounded and a message is sent to it? You won't get a notification as far as I can see.

Therefore you could also look into "pure native" frameworks to help you. By this I mean Realm or Firebase

### Realm

[Realm](https://realm.io) is a mobile database to use in your apps, compare it to Core Data for instance.

Some time last year however, Realm released something they call [Realm Mobile Platform](https://realm.io/products/realm-mobile-platform/).

As it says on the tin:

> Realm objects are always live, which means that they always have the latest data. Subscribe to notifications to get updates when data changes, then update your UI.

Maybe you could use that for your "driver side" app? Push a ride to the drivers database and it will magically be pushed to his/her device.

### Firebase

Another contender is [Firebase](https://firebase.google.com). They have something called [Firebase Realtime Database](https://firebase.google.com/products/database/) which seems to do more or less the same as Realm Mobile Platform.

So...if it was me, I think I would look into one of those two products, but...I don't know if this collides with your current node.js setup.

Hope that helps to raise your confusion to a higher level at least :)

Comment: Thanks, after looking into these, it looks like rewriting my existing framework to incorporate these (probably Firebase, as there are some good tutorials out there) will be easier than trying to make node work.  Oh well, good learning experience I guess...